# Scala: disable default toString implementation

Tags: scala, tostring, object-model

I want to create a case class that will trigger a compile-time error if it is used with `.toString()` or at least in implicit string conversion / interpolation. So far the best I came up so far is the following:

```
abstract class Identifier {
  override def toString: String = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
}
case class AttrIdentifier(name: String) extends Identifier

val obj = new NamedIdentifier("foo")

// triggers runtime exception
s"$obj + bar"
"something" + obj
```

Is there some way to disable (i.e. mark as private, hide from the scope, etc) default `toString` implementation, so it will trigger a compile-time error?

### Why am I doing this

My original goal was to replace certain objects (identifiers) in my application that were implemented using plain `String`s with a higher-level entities (custom class `Identifier`). Previously, String-based identifiers were used like:

```
val outputStr = "public function $identifier()"
```

Now it should be replaced with one of the several `Identifier` to `String` functions (which one to use actually needs to be decided in the context), for example:

```
val outputStr = "public function ${privateMemberName(identifier)}()"
val outputStr = "public function ${publicMemberName(identifier)}()"
val outputStr = "public function ${protectedMemberName(identifier)}()"
```

Now I want to locate all places that previously used this String-based identifier to analyze them and replace simple string interpolation with this `Identifier`-to-`String` function call.

Comment: Could you explain your purposes?

Comment: That would break Liskov Substitution Principle. Consider the code: `val obj: Any = new NamedIdentifier("foo"); obj.toString`. `obj` has type `Any`, and it's not possible to know at compile time, that it's actually an `Identifier`.

Comment: maybe an XY problem. What's your use case? Why do you want to be able to do that?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Added my rationale, please see the update post.

Comment: @ale64bit Added my rationale, please see the update post.

Comment: @Kolmar True enough. But can't we do anything if we *do* know that we're calling `.toString` on a `Identifier` class? Like marking a method specifically invalid to call, or something like that?

Comment: It's a common use case for type class; but you could also define a custom interpolator that handles Identifiers in a special way. (The custom interpolator can still be called `s""`.)

Comment: It seems that this is one of the language design errors Scala inherited from Java, and there is no real solution. Refactoring strings to stronger types is a common use case, and the way `toString` is implicitly called all the time (interpolation, string concatenation) has caused me countless runtime errors in the past which should have been compile-time errors.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered redefining the toString method to point to another abstract method, instead of attempting to *disable* toString?

You can do this by overriding toString and setting it equal to your identifier method, while leaving the identifier method abstract. [Here is one article that outlines the approach in Java.](http://code.scottshipp.com/2016/05/11/how-to-force-subclasses-to-implement-tostring-in-java/) It should be even simpler to do in Scala. This will force any classes extending your trait or abstract class to implement toString the way you want it.